# How should I manage in-memory data in Node?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, database-design, ecmascript-6

I have a simple app built using Node, Express, and Socket.io on the server side. My page queries my API when it needs to retrieve data that will not change, and uses WebSockets for getting live updates from the server for dynamic data. The app allows a single person, the "Supervisor", to send questions to any number of "Users" (unauthenticated) and view their answers as they trickle in. The Users send their data to the server using a POST request, and it is streamed to the Supervisor over a WebSocket. The server stores user data in a simple array, and uses an ES6 map of the items in the array (users) to objects containing each their questions and answers, like this:

```js
class User {}
let users = [], qa = new Map();
io.on('connection', socket => {
  let user = new User(socket.id);
  users.push(user);
  qa.set(user, {});
  socket.on('question-answered', ({id, answer}) => {
    let questionData = qa.get(user);
    questionData[id] = answer;
    qa.set(user, questionData);
  });
});
```

This is obviously a very primitive way of handling data, but I don't see the need for additional complexity. The data doesn't need to persist across server crashes or restarts (the user's questions and answers are also stored in localStorage), and MongoDB and even Redis just seem like overkill for this kind of data.

So my question is, am I going about this the right way? Are there any points I'm missing? I just want a simple way to store data in memory and be able to access it through client-side GET requests and socket.io. Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an array and a map provide you the type of access you need to the data and you don't need crash persistence and you have an appropriate amount of memory to hold the amount of data, then you're done.

There is no need for more than that unless your needs (query, persistence, performance, multi-user, crash recovery, backup, etc...) require something more complicated.  A simple cliche applies here: If it ain't broke, it don't need fixing.

Comment: Thanks, I understand my problem better now.

Comment: @rioc0719 - FYI, keep in mind you will have to very carefully make sure you aren't hanging on to `socket` references after the socket has disconnected or your server may use more and more memory over time.